# Which module supports select or other option for Term reference type?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there any module to support select or other option for Term reference type?

I tried with the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module but its not working in Term reference type

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox module available that adds this functionality:
https://drupal.org/sandbox/cameronbprince/1895832

Also there is an issue in the issue queue to incorporate this into the module itself: https://drupal.org/node/1716764

Alternatively, the [hierarchical_select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module also provides the option to let users add new terms to vocabularies on the node edit form.